# How to set Dependency Property of DataGridTextColumn in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, we have extended the `DataGridTextColumn` with a class named `SampleTextBoxColumn`, and created a dependency property `Sample` inside it.

Example

```
public class SampleTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Sample", typeof(object), typeof(SampleTextBoxColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Sample
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SampleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SampleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now in XAML, I want to set value of this property `Sample` depending upon conditions i.e. want to set this property inside DataTrigger.

Now Since .net does not provide a way to style the DataGridColumn, So I am not able to do this.

Or, in generic, How can we set Dependency Property of DataGridTextColumn in Style.

Comment: Columns are a bit special, since they are basically an information container, which tells the datagrid how a column should be constructed (header, cells, ...), but they are not the column in terms of the visual tree. `DataGridTextColumn` is not a `FrameworkElement` and thus it has no `Style` property. If you explain what you try to do with `Sample` maybe someone can tell you how to archieve the same result with different ways.

Comment: `DataGridTextColumn` has properties: `CellStyle`, `HeaderStyle`, `HeaderTemplate`, `ElementStyle`, `EditingElementStyle`. Use it

Comment: Hi @iRumba, Can I set the dependency property of DataGridColumn by using those properties ? for Ex. Sample in my case. if 'Yes' ,can you please explain how...

Comment: You cant use this properties in styles. grek40 said why. But you can set binding on this properties. This is an alternative trigger.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?